# PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, sql, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to show a list of data on one page that I pull from my SQL database. 
On the other page I want to show the names that are in the data. So my query is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE 'tblName.id = 'dataid';
```

Now how can I do this? I know how I can pull the data on the first page. But then, should I create a link to another page and send the id?

What's the best way to do this? Work with multipage-page template or ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push the data into an array, send it as json if it's ajax call, save it to localcache and use it as you wish.

Comment: And is it best to work on one multi-page template or different pages? If I use multi-page template, will it load all the data in one time?

Comment: if you are using jquery mobile, one page is all you need since it has an engine for changing pages already.

Comment: what you can do is also use a template framework like handlebars to have different template files for every page you call through jqm

Comment: Yes, but when I have for example 10 pages in one html file. Will it load all the pages and hide the ones that are not selected? Won't that have to load long?

Comment: no, you basically have a different div for every page, and then you load them through jquery changepage function